# PHP MongoIDs objects comparison - best practice

Tags: php, mongodb, comparison

Can somebody explain me, why the strict comparison (===) of two MongoDB\BSON\ObjectIds in PHP returns FALSE although both of ids are type MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId with the same oid?

Next question is about best practice to handle this case. Is it safe to do it via non strict comparison (==) or is there another way to do it e.g. `(string)$id1 === (string)$id2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the relevant PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php):

> When using the identity operator (`===`), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

So you should just use the standard comparison operator (`==`). No string casting required.

Per [@jh1711](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7401610/jh1711):

> BSON\ObjectId ... implements a custom object_compare handler. But the handler just compares the ids

Comment: Thanks. They are apparently not the same instances.

Comment: The first paragraph of the documentation does not apply to BSON\ObjectId, because it implements a custom object_compare handler. But the handler just compares the ids ([link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/src/BSON/ObjectId.c#L339)); so your conclusion is correct.